# Determining the "goodness" of a phrase based on "grammatical" or "contextual" relevancy

Tags: algorithm, nlp

Given a random string of words, I would like to assign a "goodness" score to the phrase, where "goodness" is some indication of **grammatical** and **contextual** relevancy.
For example:

```
"the green tree was tall" [Good score]
"delicious tires swim open" [Medium score]
"jump an con porch calmly" [Poor score]
```

I've been experimenting with the [Natural Language Toolkit](https://www.nltk.org). I'd considered using a trained tagger to assign parts-of-speech to each word in a phrase, and then parse a corpus for occurrences of that POS pattern. This may give me an indication of grammatical "goodness". However, as the tagger itself is trained on the same corpus that I'm using for validation, I can't imagine the results would be reliable. This approach also does not take into consideration the contextual relevancy of the words.
Is anyone aware of existing projects or research into this sort of thing? How would you approach this?

Comment: you might want to consider asking here, if you don't get answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: might be helpful: https://www.nltk.org/book/ch08.html

Comment: https://github.com/google-research/bert, https://github.com/huggingface/transformers

Comment: Do you have a training set of pairs comprising <sentence> <goodness score>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could employ two different approaches - supervised and semi-supervised.

**Supervised**

Assuming you have a *labeled dataset* of tuples of the form `<sentence> <goodness label>` (like the one in your examples), you could first split your dataset up in a train:test fold (e.g. 4:1).

Then you could simply use BERT feature vectors (these are pre-trained on large volumes of natural language text). The following piece of code gives you the vector for the sentence `the green tree was tall` (read more [here](https://huggingface.co/transformers/notebooks.html)).

```
nlp_features = pipeline('feature-extraction')
output = nlp_features('the green tree was tall')
np.array(output).shape   # (Samples, Tokens, Vector Size)
```

Assuming you vectorize every sentence, you could then train a simple logistc regression model (sklearn) that `learns` a set of parameters to minimize the errors in these predictions on the training set and eventually you throw the test set sentences at this model to see how it behaves.

Instead of BERT, you could also use embedded vectors as inputs to an LSTM network for training the classifier (like the one [here](https://keras.io/examples/nlp/text_classification_from_scratch/)).

**Semi-supervised**

This is applicable when you don't have sufficient labeled data (although you need a few to get you started with).

In this case, I think what you could do is to map the words of a sentence into POS tag sequences, e.g.,
`the green tree was tall` --> `ARTICLE ADJ NOUN VERB ADJ` (see [here](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml) for more details).

This step would make your method depend less on the words themselves. A model trained on these sequences would try to discover some latent distinguishing characteristics of good sentences from the bad ones.

In particular, you could run a standard text classification approach with Bidirectional LSTMs for training your classifier (this time not with words but with a much smaller vocabulary of POS tags).

Comment: Thanks for the overviews. This sent me down the ML path, along with @Adnan's article. Very interesting area of research!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a transformer model from HuggingFace that is fine tuned for sentence correctness. Specifically, the model has to be fine tuned on the Corpus of Linguistic Acceptability (CoLA). Here's a [medium article](https://towardsdatascience.com/sentence-correctness-classifier-using-transfer-learning-with-huggingface-bert-8884795ba5ca) on HuggingFace, transformers, and the fine tuning process.

You can also get a model that's already fine-tuned and you can put in the text classification pipeline for HuggingFace's transformers library [here](https://huggingface.co/textattack/roberta-base-CoLA). That site hosts fine-tuned models and you can search for a few others that are fine tuned for the CoLA task there.

Comment: Very helpful links. HuggingFace's APIs appear to be a good place to start.